# Relogin to Scraped Website on Resuming a Scrapy Job

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there a way to have a [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) spider log in to a website on resuming a previously paused scraping job?

EDIT: To clarify, my question is really about Scrapy spiders rather than cookies in general.  Perhaps a better question is whether there's any method which is called when a Scrapy spider is revived after being frozen in a job directory.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

You should be more clearer about the exact workflow of your scraper.

Anyways, I assume you are going to login when you are scraping for the first time, and want to use the same cookie while you resume the scraping.

You could use the [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) library to do something like this. Here is a code sample from their [examples page](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Examples), I have added comments for more clarity.

```
import urllib
import httplib2

http = httplib2.Http()

url = 'http://www.example.com/login'   
body = {'USERNAME': 'foo', 'PASSWORD': 'bar'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

//submitting form data for logging into the website
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(body))

//Now the 'response' object contains the cookie the website sends
//which can be used for visiting the website again

//setting the cookie for the new 'headers'
headers_2 = {'Cookie': response['set-cookie']}

url = 'http://www.example.com/home'   

// using the 'headers_2' object to visit the website,
response, content = http.request(url, 'GET', headers=headers_2)
```

In case you are not clear how cookies work, do a [search](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=how%20cookies%20work). Shortly put, 'Cookies' is a client-side technology which helps servers maintain sessions.

Comment: Oops, I missed the 'Scrapy spider' part. This would be relevant to a simple scraping script.

Comment: Thanks for the tip superxor!  As you noted, really my question is about Scrapy.  I'll edit the original to make this clear.